# Safari . How to ignore error Incorrect TLS certificate

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safari

I use Selenium Web Driver. My capabilities

```
  this.desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        this.desiredCapabilities.setCapability("enableVNC", true);
        this.desiredCapabilities.setCapability("enableVideo", false);
        this.desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
        this.desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        this.desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, this.chromeOptions);
        this.desiredCapabilities.setCapability("sessionTimeout", "15m");
```

When **desktop Safari** browser try to open the page by HTTPS, an error occurs "Incorrect TLS certificate...Failed to load  Do you want to continue ignoring the TLS errors? YES/NO"

How I can ignore this behavior for all web pages? This behavior does not occur for other browsers (Chrome/Firefox/Edge).

the following guides did not help:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/accept-insecure-certificates
https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/ssl-certificate-in-selenium/

Comment: One way to fix the error is to get a correct TLS certificate.

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about the certificate: What type of certificat is it? One of an accredited CA or a slef signed? If CA certificate, is the CA root certificate/certificate chain valid?  Is the certificate valid and usable for HTTPS server connection? If it is a server certificate, does the CN match the DNS hostname?

Comment: @StefanD. hi! the browser is launched by a remote web driver provided by Moon (Selenoid), I dont want to configure correct certificates, I want to ignore this checks. As I know the capability 'ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS' should fix this behavior, but for Safari it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Safari tighten up the security policy by removing options that are considered as insecure.

So, frankly spoken, if you try to fix your issue with a workaround or 'dirty hack' you just postpone it to a later date and browser version. The only way out is IMHO to get things done the right way and solve the problem.

Request a new certificate from a official Certification Authority if you need public access to your server or set up your own CA to get rid of the 'self-signed certificate' trap.

Seting up a CA is not the big thing. Ther is a lot of free/open-source and commercial tools available so you can choose one that fits best your needs.

Creating your root and server certificate is done in no time. Installing the new certificate in the server is a bit more because you have a downtime. And last but not least your own root certificate must be installed in the browsers truststore for user certificates. But that's also a easy task.

The benefit of this way is that you are done even if you update your browser.